# How can I solve "Cannot access <ObjectName>" warning?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations

This is my ExamResult class

```
@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class ExamResult {
    int class1;
    int credit1;
    int class2;
    int credit2;
    int class3;
    int credit3;
    int class4;
    int credit4;
    int class5;
    int credit5;
    int class6;
    int credit6;
}
```

And this is my main class

```
    CalculateService calculate = new CalculateService();
    calculate.calculateSPA(examResult)); //I'm trying to do this
```

But I got this message. The code is runable this is a just warning.

```
Cannot access spa_calculation.ExamResult

spa_calculation.CalculateService 
public float calculateSPA(@NotNull spa_calculation.ExamResult examResult)
Inferred annotations:
@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
  custom-tests.main
```

Comment: What's the value of `examResult` in your code?

Comment: Where did you see this message? It's not a message from the Java compiler. Is it appearing as a pop-up when you hover your mouse pointer over the code in IntelliJ IDEA? If that's the case, you should add a tag to clarify the IDE you're using.

Comment: @Rogue I just set the all of examResult values

Comment: @k314159 yes exactly as you said. I added thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the information that you've given, it looks like you're getting a warning related to the `@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)` annotation on the `ExamResults` class. This annotation causes all fields in the `ExamResults` class to become private by default. I would recommend removing the annotation and instead making the fields private yourself. The difference here is that your IDE likely does not support this annotation (it does not know the meaning of this annotation for field access), whereas it does support tagging your fields with `private` (e.g. `private int class1;`), resulting in more specific compile errors if this is indeed the problem.